# How to make cloud firestore security rules such that logged in users can access only their data?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am new to Cloud Firestore and I am unable to complete a task. I want that each logged in user should be able to see their own data, i.e., each logged in user can only see the data he/she has created and not other's data. Currently when I log in with different users, every user is able to see everything stored in Firestore database. I tried many tutorials and documentations, but my case seems to be different and I am unable to apply their method in my app.

Please have a look at my Firestore Database's screenshots given below:

This is the 'users' collection in which the document id is same as the Firebase `uid` provided when the user is logged in using email password login method:
[image: This is the 'users' collection]

And this is the 'venues' collection in which the document id is auto-generated and field values are entered by the user in the app.
[image]

This is the code in my Firestore Security Rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{uid} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    match /users/{uid} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null;
    }
    match /{document=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Please help me out!**

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what's wrong with what you have now, including code that performs queries against these rules that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: The first issue is the rules shown in the question have nothing to do with the data stored in Firestore (documents?). Secondly if you want to limit what data can be seen, you need to have some type of ownership of that data - generally speaking you would include the users uid in the document that belongs to them. Seeing as the documents in the venues collection don't have that, you won't have a way to lock it down. Lastly, if you plan on using the email to tie them together, that could cause long term issues as email addresses change. The uid is a better option.

Comment: Thank you, I solved my problem by making venues as a sub-collection inside the user collection where each document of the user collection is the uid of the logged in user and then I applied the security rule --> allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;

Answer (score 5):

State the security rule for one path only once - you used for users/{uid} first time correct settings, and next to them allow to read to all who is logged in

```
rules_version = '2';
   service cloud.firestore {
     match /databases/{database}/documents {
       match /users/{uid} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
     }}}
```

`request.auth.uid == uid` rule usually used for letting user access only docs, that named with their id. U had them right in first statement.

`resource.data.nameOfTheField == 'fieldContent'` user gets access to file if its `nameOfTheField` in firestore already contains `fieldContent` value.

`request.resource.data.nameOfTheField == fieldValue` rules validates operation if requested data to `nameOfTheField` will be changed to `fieldValue`

You may allow operation based on other collections data:
`get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true` will allow data operation if user is admin in admin field of users document.

Remember that you can validate with any operator that resolves to boolean, so you can use > < for example when validating integer fields values.